# Professor gets a java.io.FileNotFoundException but I don't?

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

I had a project for my Java class where the user enters patients for a hospital then the program reads a file and the user can choose to amend their added patients to the file, print it out to the screen, or both. The program works perfectly in NetBeans for me but in the professor's comments, he says his compiler got a FileNotFoundException(Edit: It is actually a runtime error), even though I included the file in the package. When I emailed him, he only repeated that he received a FileNotFoundException.
Here is the code:

```
    package realworldproblem3;


import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class xyzHospital {

static int numOfPat;
static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
static String inp;
static ArrayList<Patient> p = new ArrayList<>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {  
   boolean done = false;

           importPatients();
           System.out.print("Add new patients to the report:\n");
           while (done == false){
               addPatient();
               System.out.print("Are you done adding patients? (Y or N)\n");
               inp = input.nextLine();
               switch (inp.toLowerCase()){
                   case "y": done = true;
                   break;
                   case "n": done = false;
                   break;
                   default: System.out.print("You did not enter a valid character. The program will print results then exit.\n\n");
                   done = true;
                   break;
               }

           }
           printAll();

       }






static public void addPatient(){
     numOfPat++;
     Patient pat = new Patient();
     p.add(pat);
     pat.addInfo(numOfPat);
 }

static public void printAll() throws IOException{
    System.out.print("Do you want to output the report to the screen ('S'), to a file ('F'), or both('B')?\n");
    inp = input.next();
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("XYZHospitalExampleData-1.txt");
    switch (inp.toLowerCase()){
        case "s":
             System.out.print("\t\t\t\t\tXYZ Community Hospital\t\t\n=============================================================================================================\n");
             System.out.printf("%-14s%30s%38s%n", "    Name", "Address", "Payment Information");
             System.out.printf("%-8s%-8s%15s%10s%10s%8s%15s%15s%15s %n", "Last", "First", "Address Line 1", "City", "State", "Zip", "Payment Date", "Payment Amt.","Amount Owed");
             System.out.print("=============================================================================================================\n");
            for(int i = 0; i<numOfPat;i++){
                p.get(i).print();
            }
            break;

        case "f": 
            writer.print(""); //writes over file so there is no duplicate patients
            writer.close();
            for(int i = 0; i<numOfPat;i++){
                p.get(i).printToFile();
            }
            break;

        case "b":
             System.out.print("\t\t\t\t\tXYZ Community Hospital\t\t\n=============================================================================================================\n");
             System.out.printf("%-14s%30s%38s%n", "    Name", "Address", "Payment Information");
             System.out.printf("%-8s%-8s%15s%10s%10s%8s%15s%15s%15s %n", "Last", "First", "Address Line 1", "City", "State", "Zip", "Payment Date", "Payment Amt.","Amount Owed");
             System.out.print("=============================================================================================================\n");
            writer.print("");
            writer.close();
            for(int i = 0; i<numOfPat;i++){
                p.get(i).printToFile();
                p.get(i).print();
            }
            break;
}
}

//each patient from the file is added as a patient object
 static public void importPatients() throws IOException{
     try(Scanner read = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("XYZHospitalExampleData-1.txt")))) {
          while(read.hasNextLine()){ //one more line means that there is another patient to add
                    numOfPat++;
                    read.nextLine();
         }

          read.close();

          try(Scanner r = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("XYZHospitalExampleData-1.txt")))) {
                    for (int j=0; j < numOfPat; j++){

                        String line = r.nextLine();
                        Patient pat = new Patient();
                        p.add(pat);
                        String[] str = line.split("\\^"); //the delimiter ^ is used to separate information in the file

                        for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
                            if(str[i].isEmpty()||str[i].matches("0")||str[i] == null){ //if str[i] is empty, that means that it will be skipped over
                                i++;
                            }
                            switch (i){
                                case 0: p.get(j).ID = Integer.parseInt(str[i]);
                                break;
                                case 1: p.get(j).nameLast = str[i];
                                break;
                                case 2: p.get(j).nameFirst = str[i];
                                break;
                                case 3: p.get(j).address = str[i];
                                break;
                                case 4: p.get(j).opAddr = str[i];
                                break;
                                case 5: p.get(j).city = str[i];
                                break;
                                case 6: p.get(j).state = str[i];
                                break;
                                case 7: p.get(j).zip = Integer.parseInt(str[i]);
                                break;
                                case 8: p.get(j).optZip = Integer.parseInt(str[i]);
                                break;
                                case 9: p.get(j).payDate = str[i];
                                break;
                                case 10: p.get(j).payment = Double.parseDouble(str[i]);
                                break;
                                case 11: p.get(j).owed = Double.parseDouble(str[i]);
                                break;
                                default: System.out.print("Error.\n");
                                break;
                            }
                      }
                    }
                    r.close(); 
                   }
            }
 }
}
```

Here is the patient class:

```
package realworldproblem3;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


public class Patient {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
 String nameFirst, nameLast, address, opAddr,city, state, payDate;
 int zip, optZip, ID;
 double owed, payment;


 public void print() {
    System.out.printf("%-8s%-9s%-20s%-10s%-8s%-7s%-15s%-11.2f%-10.2f%n", nameLast, nameFirst, address, city, state, zip, payDate, owed, payment);
 }

 public void printToFile()throws IOException{
    try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("XYZHospitalExampleData-1.txt", true))) {
        writer.write(ID + "^" + nameLast+ "^" + nameFirst + "^" + address + "^" + opAddr + "^" + city + "^" + state + "^" + zip + "^" + optZip + "^"+  payDate  + "^" + payment + "^" + owed +"\n");
        writer.close();
    }
 }
 private void setName(){
   System.out.print("Enter patient's first name.\n"); //user is asked for all information
    nameFirst = input.nextLine();                       //first three inputs use nextLine so it consumes the end of line character, so the address will be put in the string correctly.
     System.out.print("Enter patient's last name.\n");  //if next() is used, the address is cut off at the first whitespace and the other elements of the address
    nameLast = input.nextLine();                                //are stored in the upcoming inputs.
    if (nameFirst.isEmpty()||nameLast.isEmpty()){
        System.out.print("You must enter the first and last name.\n");
        setName();
    }
 }
 public String getName(){
     return nameFirst + " " + nameLast;
 }

 private void setAddr(){
      System.out.print("Enter patient's address.\n");
    address = input.nextLine();
    if (address.isEmpty()){
        System.out.print("You must enter the patients address.\n");
        setAddr();
    }
 }
 public String getAddr(){
     return address;
 }

 private void setCity(){
     System.out.print("Enter patient's home city.\n");
    city = input.nextLine();
    if(city.isEmpty()){
        System.out.print("You must enter the patients city.\n");
        setCity();
    }
 }
 public String getCity(){
     return city;
 }

 private void setState(){
      System.out.print("Enter patient's state.\n");
    state = input.nextLine();
    if(state.isEmpty()){
        System.out.print("You must enter the patients state.\n");
        setState();
    }
 }
 public String getState(){
     return state;
 }

 private void setDate(){
      System.out.print("Enter the payment date.\n");
    payDate = input.next();
    if(payDate.isEmpty()){
        System.out.print("You must enter a payment date.\n");
        setDate();
    }
 }
 public String getDate(){
     return payDate;
 }

 private void setZip(){
     System.out.print("Enter patient's zipcode.\n");
    try{
        zip = input.nextInt();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.print("You must enter a valid 5-digit zipcode.\n");
        input.next();
        setZip();  //if it says that the setZip call will make the function loop infinitely, it is just a warning, it will not loop infinitely.
    }
    int length = String.valueOf(zip).length();
    if(length != 5 && zip > 0){
      System.out.print("You must enter a valid 5-digit zipcode.\n");
      setZip();        
    }

 }
 public int getZip(){
     return zip;
 }

 private void setOwed(){
     System.out.print("Enter patient's due balance.\n");
    try{
        owed = input.nextDouble();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.print("Amount has to be a non-negative number.\n");
        input.next();
        setOwed();
    }
    int length = String.valueOf(owed).length();
    if (owed <0 || length == 0){
        System.out.print("Amount has to be a non-negative number.\n");
        setOwed();
    }
 }
 public double getOwed(){
     return owed;
 }

 private void setPayment(){
      System.out.print("Enter patient's payment amount.\n");
    try{
        payment = input.nextDouble();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
         System.out.print("Payment amount has to be a positive number less than the amount owed.\n");
         input.next();
        setPayment();
    }
    int length = String.valueOf(payment).length();
    if(payment < 0 || length ==0 || payment > owed){
        System.out.print("Payment amount has to be a positive number less than the amount owed.\n");
        setPayment();
    }
 }
 public double getPayment(){
     return payment;
 }

 private void setID(int Id){
     ID = Id;
 }
 public int getID(){
     return ID;
 }

 public void addInfo(int ID){
     setID(ID);
     setName();
     setAddr();
     setCity();
     setState();
     setZip();
     setOwed();
     setPayment();
     setDate();
 }


}
```

And here is the file XYZHospitalExampleData-1.txt:

12345^Jones^John^1234 Test Drive^PO box 123^Test City^IN^11234^1234^12/05/2015^250.0^25000.0
12346^Jones^Sara^1234 Test Drive^PO box 123^Test City^IN^11234^1234^12/20/2017^50.0^50000.0
12347^Doe^John^1235 XYZ Drive^null^Test City^IN^11234^0^01/05/2016^350.0^56799.0
12348^Doe^Sara^1235 XYZ Drive^null^Test City^IN^11234^0^11/09/2017^100.0^5020.52
12349^Lawson^Lonnie^12 South Drive^null^Test City^IN^11236^0^03/15/2013^253.51^25065.52
12349^Anderson^Sara^156 North Avenue^null^Test City^IN^11246^0^05/05/2013^21.33^251.56
12350^Smith^Andy^2455 East Street^null^Test City^IN^11246^0^12/05/2017^365.21^2543.33

It starts with their ID and ends with the amount that they owe. Any help to understand why my professor's compiler is giving him an error would be appreciated, and what I can do to be sure that it will be able to find the file so I do not have this problem again.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] as it would help us to only see the relevant code where the error appears.

Comment: "*[...] his compiler got a FileNotFoundException*" - That is unlikely. The compiler normally creates error messages. `Exception`s are thrown at runtime.

Comment: Ask your professor to send you the stack trace, including the references to the lines in your program where the exception came from, and also tell you what they were doing at the time the exception happened. This is the bare minimum you need as a bug report. (And by not telling you all of that automatically they're setting you a bad example!) You should also make sure that you give them clear instructions as to where your data file should go, in case that's the issue. Or if it genuinely is the compiler raising the exception (?) there's still more information they can give you in that case too.

Comment: Better yet, go see your professor in person and have them demonstrate the problem to you. And hopefully you can demonstrate to them that it does work instead.

Comment: Sorry, it was at runtime that he got the FileNotFoundException I misspoke! And he has us zip the entire project file, so the .txt file is in the same folder regardless.

Comment: I asked for the stack trace with references to the lines @Rup Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: XYZHospitalExampleData-1.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at realworldproblem3.xyzHospital.importPatients(xyzHospital.java:95)
 at realworldproblem3.xyzHospital.main(xyzHospital.java:22)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the beginning of your `main` method you call `importPatients` which reads data from the `XYZHospitalExampleData-1.txt` file. If this file is not present, you'll get an exception (in the runtime, not a compiler error).

Most probably something went wrong when your package was unpackaged. Maybe the file was not copied to the expected location, something like that. One of the ways to address this would be to catch the `FileNotFoundException` and to display a message describing what went wrong and what is expected.